# Проблема с меммапингом в Gensim

Tags: python, nlp, gensim

Я использую gensim для создания модели fasttext. Gensim поддерживает mmap для загрузки векторов в ленивом режиме с диска, но в моем случае KeyedVectors.load(fname, mmap="r") медленнее в 5 раз, по сравнению с KeyedVectors.load(fname). Видел вот такой тред: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42986405/how-to-speed-up-gensim-word2vec-model-load-time/43067907#43067907 пытался из него понять, что происходит. Ось Ubuntu 20.04, python 3.8, gensim 4.2.0. Что я делаю не так?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А диск какой? Если HDD, то реально может упираться в скорость диска просто, получается вместо чтобы один раз с диска прочитать последовательно, оно по нему бегает туда-сюда, а для HDD это очень затратная операция.

Comment: HDD, сейчас попробую на SSD